# selenium-webdriver not getting installed in ubuntu using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, ubuntu, npm

I am using ubuntu 16 and have downloaded nodejs and npm

`sudo apt install curl`

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -`
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -`

`sudo apt install nodejs`

nodejs and version: `nodejs -v` is 8.12.0 and `npm -v` is 6.4.1

then I ran the command `npm install selenium-webdriver` and got the bellow error

> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
>   
> npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
>   
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND domain domain:8080
>   
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>   
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>   
> npm ERR! network 
>   
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>   
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   
> npm ERR!     /home/uzma/.npm/_logs/2018-11-21T07_43_02_442Z-debug.log

Comment: Do you need proxy to access public network? The error saids npm can't accees https://registry.npmjs.org.

Comment: How to access it?